# IOS loading failure on large (more than 50) images using swiper

Tags: swiper.js

trying to build a website with swiper with bigger number of photos.
On various browsers on Mac and PC it works well, but fail on ios safari after more than 50 images are within my images array.
Failure is that IOS Safari try to load the page, refreshes automatically and try again and again, then show a message saying that website loading failed.

Same on IOS Firefox works.

The source I build up using some PHP within a CMS (LEPTON), after collection the image names (without size & extension) within an array:

```
foreach( $aImages as $image )
{
    $div .= '       <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="' . $image . '" >' . PHP_EOL;
    $div .= '           <img data-src="' . $imageURL . $image . '_8b.png" data-srcset="' . $imageURL . $image . '_24b.png 1200w" class="swiper-lazy">' . PHP_EOL;
    $div .= '           <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>' . PHP_EOL;
    $div .= '       </div>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

my JS to initialize the slider looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize swiper when document ready
    var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
        /* parameters with different value than default */
        // Duration of transition between slides (in ms)
        speed: 1400,
        // fading effect
        effect: 'fade',
        fadeEffect: {
            crossFade: true
        },
        // show hand on image
        grabCursor: true,
        // add visibility class to currently showing image
        watchSlidesProgress: true,
        watchSlidesVisibility: true,
        // Lazy Loading
        preloadImages: false,
        lazy: {
            loadPrevNext: true,
            loadPrevNextAmount: 1,
            loadOnTransitionStart: true,
        },
        // continuous loop mode
        loop: true,
        // double click zoom into image
        zoom: false,
        // enable keyboard navigation prev/next
        keyboard: {
            enabled: true,
            onlyInViewport: true,
            pageUpDown: true,
        },
        // Navigation arrows
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            hideOnClick: false,
        },
        // center image
        centeredSlides: true,
        centeredSlidesBounds: false,
        // autoplay
        autoplay: {
            delay: 3000,
            disableOnInteraction: true
        },
        autoplay: false,
    });
```

Any idea what's wrong or what I can change in order to solve my issue ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution for my problem are the virtual slides ....
Testing this but getting other issues there ....
And the available examples in native JS does not really help.

Update: Finally I got it running with virtual slides.
However there is a bug within combination with fadings.
Without fade parameter it is running.